I have an issue with k8s startup probes where when it meets mongoClient (pymongo), my pods will stuck in unready state
def test_mongodb(conn_str):  
    logging.debug("testing Mongo...")    
    try:           
        start_time = time.time()  # Start timing           
        client = MongoClient(conn_str)           
        info = client.server_info()           
        end_time = time.time()  # End timing           
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time           
        logging.debug(f"MongoDB connection check took {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")
        logging.debug("Mongodb server info: %s", info)           
        print("MongoDB Server Information:", info)             
        return True      
    except Exception as e:                    
        logging.debug(f"mongo failed: {str(e)}")              
        return False

test_mongodb(conn_str)

Helm chart for the startup probe
startupProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 60
  failureThreshold: 6
  exec:
    command:
    - python
    - /app/start.py

my pods will become unready state. so its not even an uncaught error. there is no error to begin with. I can see on the logs that the probe return success.
the helm release logs would give me: "context deadline error"/"client rate limiter".
but if i comment the line:
# client = MongoClient(conn_str) 
# info = client.server_info()

my pods will work just fine with no restart by the probes.

Please include session parameter while using server_info method.  More details of method are in https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.server_info.  Also please pass correct mongodb url in test_mongodb method.  include module imports

@NatarajMedayhal The mongodb url is correct. The code that I posted is just a snippet. when the startup probe executes the start.py, there will be no errors. and if I go into the log file that I write it to, it will log successfully with no catch to that method.
If I execute the start.py by manually go into the pods, it will work with no errors. even the startup probe would produce no errors. Its just that 2 lines that I comment would make my pods stuck in unready state.
My helm release somehow gives me "context deadline error"/"client rate limiter".
